# How to support new column creation based on inserted data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to `MySQL` and was trying to find a way to handle `dynamic` column creation based on inserted data. For example, if I insert some data into below table, the specific data related to aa gets into `dummy_{specific extension`} column which is `dummy_aa`. Same goes with `dummy_bb`

```
create table dummy(
   id INT, 
   dummy_aa VARCHAR(100), 
   dummy_bb VARCHAR(100), 
   dummy_age VARCHAR(100), 
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

insert into dummy values 
(1, aa, 15),
(2, aa, 17),
(3, bb, 18),
(4, bb, 19);
```

But, when I have new data to insert with a different name, say like below, I want the `cc` value to get into `dummy_cc` column which dosent exist.

```
insert into dummy values (5, cc, 20)
```

What could be the best way to create dynamic columns in MySQL without any performance implications and what would be the best way to check if the column exists before each insert (I a not sure if there exists a better way then checking for column to exist).

Comment: You seem to be missing some inverted commas. Is that deliberate?

Comment: But, in general, I think it's best to handle issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0):

The general answer here is that the `dummy_aa`, `dummy_bb`, etc. columns probably should not even exist.  Instead, use this schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dummy (
    id INT,
    dummy_code VARCHAR(100),
    dummy_group INT,
    dummy_age INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

That is, maintain a *single* column for the dummy type/code.  Then your 4 sample inserts would become:

```sql
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (1, 1, 'aa', 15);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (2, 1, 'aa', 17);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (3, 2, 'bb', 18);
INSERT INTO dummy VALUES (4, 2, 'bb', 19);
```

Now when you want to *view* separate columns for the dummy types, do a pivot query:

```sql
SELECT
    dummy_group,
    MAX(CASE WHEN dummy_code = 'aa' THEN dummy_age END) AS dummy_aa,
    MAX(CASE WHEN dummy_code = 'bb' THEN dummy_age END) AS dummy_bb
FROM dummy
GROUP BY
    dummy_group;
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that pivoting would be a good answer, but, we want to see these columns created instead.

Comment: ... and that's bad practice, to add database columns like this.  Adding more _data_ to a SQL table is supposed to mean adding new _rows_, not columns.  You should rethink your design (my answer is one suggestion).

Comment: But, isn't the case statement bad either as we do get these values dynamically, but, what I see here is hardcoded to 2 values aa and bb. How to handle if these values come in greater number.

Comment: You can add more case expressions, or use dynamic SQL to generate the query.  Dynamic SQL to add more columns _is_ good practice; nothing wrong with that.